# RadioButton on the first Column of a TreeTable (Primefaces)

Tags: primefaces, radio-button, treetable

I have a treeTable where I have to set on the first column a Radionbutton.
the RadionButton is not linked to the treeTable.
I tried with the selectionMode but in vain.
If you have any idea, please share it with me.
Thanks in advance :)

My treeTable should look like this :
[image]

here is the code I used :

```
<p:treeTable value="#{treeBouchon.racine}" var="ligneBudgetaire"
                        selection="#{treeBouchon.ligneBudgetaireselectionnee}"
                        selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{ligneBudgetaire.id}">



                        <p:column selectionMode="single">
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Ligne budgétaire">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ligneBudgetaire.filed1}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="ETP reçus">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ligneBudgetaire.filed2}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="ETP émis">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ligneBudgetaire.filed3}" />
                        </p:column

                    </p:treeTable>
```